# addRole to a mentioned user isn't working

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot, which can add a specific role to an user.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', (message) => {
    let allowedRole = message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "Streamer");
    let gRole = message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "Stream 1");
    mention = message.mentions.users.first();
    let member = message.mentions.users.first();
  if (message.content === "addRole") {
      members.get(message.mentions.user.id).addRole(gRole);
  }
});

client.login('mytoken');
```

I expect that the bot can add role to a specific person

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your first mistake was, that you searched for channel names and not role names in your variable `gRole` and `allowedRole`. I changed this 2 variables, **so they search for roles instead of channels.**

You defined twice the same, once as mention and once as `member = message.mentions.users.first()`. Because of this, I removed your variable named `mention` and used the variable `member`. I found that the code for this variable didn't match the name of the variable because your code returned the **user Object** and I changed it to the **member Object** (because your variable is named member).

Lastly, I used your **predefined variable** `member` and assigned the role `gRole` to it, so you don't have to get the member another time.

---

Try to use the following code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', message => {
    const allowedRole = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === 'Streamer'); // isn't used
    const gRole = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === 'Stream 1');
    const member = message.mentions.members.first();
    if (message.content === 'addRole') {
        member.addRole(gRole);
    }
});

client.login('mytoken');
```

Comment: I tried it and it didn't responded anything (I changed the token to mine already)

Comment: What do you mean that it didn‘t respond? @SirCyborg

Comment: I wrote addRole with @username but the user didn't got the role.